# Assigning RCREG value to a variable clears it

Tags: microcontroller, uart, microchip

Sorry to bother you, but I've been encountering an issue while trying to assign data from RCREG to a variable. In all the other PICs I've used (currently using 18F4550), it was quite straightforward. I would simply use something like:

`new_variable = RCREG;`

However, now when I do this, it seems to clear RCREG and doesn't transfer anything to the variable where I intend to store the value. Here's the code snippet for reference:

---

**Edit 1:**

Hey! Thanks for the tips. I'm new here, still learning how to post. I'll check @the_busybee's links. First, let me clarify my earlier point.

In `v_aux2 = RCREG;` line, it should transfer RCREG's value to `v_aux2`. While debugging, I set breakpoints in that line and `NOP();` to pause, checking if the value written in RCREG via MPLAB X's SFR window is assigned to `v_aux2`. The issue: when the processor stops at `NOP();`, 0 is written to `v_aux2`. It's like the RCREG was read and cleared before its value been assigned to `v_aux2`.

And my question is: What could cause this?

What I want and expect is assign the hex value 0x55 to variable `v_aux2` via RCREG.

I will post my configuration function here to:

```c
void config_serial(void)
{
    TRISCbits.RC7 = 1; // sets RC7 as RX
    TRISCbits.RC6 = 1; // sets RC6 as TX
    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1; // configures TX/RX pins as serial pins
    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0; // selects asynchronous mode
    TXSTAbits.TX9 = 1; // sets 9-bit transmission
    TXSTAbits.BRGH = 0; // selects low-speed baud rate generator
    // TXEN = 1; bit that enables serial transmission (brings TX pin to 5 Volts)
    // TXSTAbits.SENDB = 1; sends 8 bits of 0 as a frame end detection
    RCSTAbits.RX9 = 1; // enables 9-bit detection
    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; // disables continuous bit reception
    RCSTAbits.ADDEN = 1; // enables address detection along with interruption
    BAUDCONbits.RCIDL = 0; // ensures bit reception is active
    BAUDCONbits.TXCKP = 0; // TX data is not inverted
    BAUDCONbits.RXDTP = 0; // received data is not inverted
    PIE1bits.TXIE = 0; // disables interrupt for data to be transmitted
    PIE1bits.RCIE = 1; // enables interrupt for data reception
    BAUDCONbits.WUE = 0; // wake up enable bit
    BAUDCONbits.BRG16 = 0;
    SPBRG = 0x1F; // selects baud rate generator for 19200 kilobaud
    TXEN = 1;
    OERR = 0;
    FERR = 0;
}
```

**edit 2:**

Thank you once again for the tips, and let's dive into the details. Yes, I do observe the value 0x55 in RCREG before the compiler proceeds and executes the line. To inspect the machine code, I utilize the 'disassembly' window in MPLAB X. I'm unsure if this is the correct approach, so I appreciate your guidance.

To be honest, I don't have much experience in assembly coding, and I'm having difficulty understanding what the code is conveying. I'll share it here for your assistance. Your insights would be immensely helpful guys.

The code in Assembly:

```
!void recebe_serial(void)
!{
!    //TMR0IE = 0;
!        if(OERR)// overload error detected 
0x354: BTFSS RCSTA, 1, ACCESS
0x356: BRA 0x362
!        {
!            OERR = 0;
0x358: BCF RCSTA, 1, ACCESS
!            /*serial comunication reinicialized*/
!    
!            CREN = 0;
0x35A: BCF RCSTA, 4, ACCESS
!            CREN = 1;
0x35C: BSF RCSTA, 4, ACCESS
!        
!            if (FERR)
0x35E: BTFSC RCSTA, 2, ACCESS
!            {
!                //in future implement timer 1 here
!                FERR = 0;
0x360: BCF RCSTA, 2, ACCESS
!            }
!        }
!    static ui8b index = INICIAL_VALUE_PROG;
!    
!    ui8b v_aux2 = RCREG;
0x362: MOVFF RCREG, v_aux2
0x364: NOP
!    NOP();
0x366: NOP
!    //transmite_serial(v_aux);
!    if (v_aux2 == 0x55) 
0x368: MOVLW 0x55
0x36A: XORWF v_aux2, W, ACCESS
0x36C: BTFSS STATUS, 2, ACCESS
0x36E: RETURN 0
!    {
!        recebe[endereco] = (RCREG ^ BYTE_MASK_PROG);
0x370: MOVF RCREG, W, ACCESS
0x372: XORLW 0x55
0x374: MOVWF recebe, ACCESS
!        ADEN = 0;
0x376: BCF RCSTA, 3, ACCESS
!        RCIF = 0;
0x378: BCF PIR1, 5, ACCESS
!        //liga_desliga_cargas(1, idc);
!        while(index < QTD_DATA_PROG)
0x37A: BRA 0x398
0x398: MOVLW 0x5
0x39A: CPFSGT index, ACCESS
0x39C: BRA 0x37C
!        {
!            if(RCIF)
0x37C: BTFSS PIR1, 5, ACCESS
0x37E: BRA 0x398
!            {
!                recebe[index] = RCREG ^ BYTE_MASK_PROG;
0x380: MOVF index, W, ACCESS
0x382: MULLW 0x1
0x384: MOVLW 0x1
0x386: ADDWF PROD, W, ACCESS
0x388: MOVWF FSR2, ACCESS
0x38A: MOVLW 0x0
0x38C: ADDWFC PRODH, W, ACCESS
0x38E: MOVWF FSR2H, ACCESS
0x390: MOVF RCREG, W, ACCESS
0x392: XORLW 0x55
0x394: MOVWF INDF2, ACCESS
!                index++;
0x396: INCF index, F, ACCESS
!            }
!        }
!        if (index == QTD_DATA_PROG)
0x39E: MOVLW 0x6
0x3A0: XORWF index, W, ACCESS
0x3A2: BTFSS STATUS, 2, ACCESS
0x3A4: BRA 0x3AC
!        {
!            index = INICIAL_VALUE_PROG;
0x3A6: MOVLW 0x1
0x3A8: MOVWF index, ACCESS
!            ADEN = 1;
0x3AA: BSF RCSTA, 3, ACCESS
!        }   
!        menu_fct_slaves();
0x3AC: CALL 0x100, 0
0x3AE: NOP
0x3B0: RETURN 0
```

---

**edit 3**
Hey, I've been testing this code in MPLAB again. This time, I observed a change in the assembly code that seems a bit confusing to me. What caught my attention is the line I marked with '**', which reads: 0x2B2: MOVFF RCREG, qtd_int_ext. However, when I hover my mouse over 'qtd_int_ext', it indicates that the variable is out of scope. If my basic knowlege in assembly is right it should be like: 0x2B2: MOVFF RCREG, v_aux2. Right?

Here's the snippet:

```
!void recebe_serial(void)
!{
!    //TMR0IE = 0;
!        if(OERR)// erro de sobre carga detectado 
0x2A4: BTFSS RCSTA, 1, ACCESS
0x2A6: BRA 0x2B2
!        {
!            OERR = 0;//zerado flag em software
0x2A8: BCF RCSTA, 1, ACCESS
!            /*serial comunication reinicialized*/
!    
!            CREN = 0;
0x2AA: BCF RCSTA, 4, ACCESS
!            CREN = 1;
0x2AC: BSF RCSTA, 4, ACCESS
!        
!            if (FERR)
0x2AE: BTFSC RCSTA, 2, ACCESS
!            {
!                FERR = 0;
0x2B0: BCF RCSTA, 2, ACCESS
!            }
!        }
!    static ui8b index = INICIAL_VALUE_PROG;
!    
!    ui8b v_aux2 = RCREG;
**0x2B2: MOVFF RCREG, qtd_int_ext**//strange assembly line. 
0x2B4: NOP
!    NOP();
0x2B6: NOP
!    //transmite_serial(v_aux);
!    if (v_aux2 == 0x55) 
0x2B8: MOVLW 0x55
0x2BA: XORWF v_aux2, W, ACCESS
0x2BC: BTFSS STATUS, 2, ACCESS
0x2BE: RETURN 0
!    {
!        recebe[endereco] = (RCREG ^ BYTE_MASK_PROG);
0x2C0: MOVF RCREG, W, ACCESS
0x2C2: XORLW 0x55
0x2C4: MOVWF recebe, ACCESS
!        ADEN = 0;
0x2C6: BCF RCSTA, 3, ACCESS
!        RCIF = 0;
0x2C8: BCF PIR1, 5, ACCESS
!        //liga_desliga_cargas(1, idc);
!        while(index < QTD_DATA_PROG)
0x2CA: BRA 0x2E8
0x2E8: MOVLW 0x5
0x2EA: CPFSGT index, ACCESS
0x2EC: BRA 0x2CC
!        {
!            if(RCIF)
0x2CC: BTFSS PIR1, 5, ACCESS
0x2CE: BRA 0x2E8
!            {
!                recebe[index] = RCREG ^ BYTE_MASK_PROG;
0x2D0: MOVF index, W, ACCESS
0x2D2: MULLW 0x1
0x2D4: MOVLW 0x1
0x2D6: ADDWF PROD, W, ACCESS
0x2D8: MOVWF FSR2, ACCESS
0x2DA: MOVLW 0x0
0x2DC: ADDWFC PRODH, W, ACCESS
0x2DE: MOVWF FSR2H, ACCESS
0x2E0: MOVF RCREG, W, ACCESS
0x2E2: XORLW 0x55
0x2E4: MOVWF INDF2, ACCESS
!                index++;
0x2E6: INCF index, F, ACCESS
!            }
!        }
!        if (index == QTD_DATA_PROG)
0x2EE: MOVLW 0x6
0x2F0: XORWF index, W, ACCESS
0x2F2: BTFSS STATUS, 2, ACCESS
0x2F4: BRA 0x2FC
!        {
!            index = INICIAL_VALUE_PROG
0x2F6: MOVLW 0x1
0x2F8: MOVWF index, ACCESS
!            ADEN = 1;
0x2FA: BSF RCSTA, 3, ACCESS
!        }   
!        menu_fct_slaves();
0x2FC: CALL 0x100, 0
```

---

```c
void recebe_serial(void)
{
    //TMR0IE = 0;
    if (OERR) // over load error detected 
    {
        OERR = 0; //flag cleared
        /*serial comunication reinicialized*/

        CREN = 0;
        CREN = 1;
    
        if (FERR)
        {
            //in future set timer 1 to watch for this flag
            FERR = 0;
        }
    }
    static ui8b index = 0x00;
    
    ui8b v_aux2 = 0x00;
    v_aux2 = RCREG;
    NOP();
    //transmite_serial(v_aux);

    if (v_aux2 == 0x55) //faz um byte mask para saber se o endereço sendo chamdo é o mesmo
    {
        recebe[endereco] = (RCREG ^ BYTE_MASK_PROG);
        ADEN = 0;
        RCIF = 0;
        while (index < QTD_DATA_PROG)
        {
            if (RCIF)
            {
                recebe[index] = RCREG ^ BYTE_MASK_PROG;
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (index == QTD_DATA_PROG)
        {
            index = INICIAL_VALUE_PROG;
            ADEN = 1;
        }   
        //TMR0IE = 1;
    }
}
```

The preceding code is a function that initially receives a value from RCREG. Utilizing the RX9D for address detection, it compares the received value to check if the device has been addressed. Following that, it proceeds to populate another variable with data, which I utilize in other sections of my program.

I apologize for bothering you with such a straightforward question, but I can't believe I've spent an entire day on this and still haven't been able to solve the problem.

I would like to add that I tested this program in MPLAB X v3.65 debugger, and my compiler is XC8 v1.40.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and perhaps some more of the [help]. -- I have formatted your question, which lacks an actual question, but you might want to know _why this is_. Additionally, please [edit] your question to add new information. This is not a forum.

Comment: And what do you mean by "_doesn't transfer anything to the variable_"? Any assignment stores a value in the target location. What is stored, and what do you expect? -- Oh, and please translate all identifiers and comments to English.

Comment: The setup for USART may vary from model to model. How about your setup code? How do you initialize the USART module?

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Did you see the 0x55 in RCREG before the assignment? The next step is now to look into the generated machine code. Sometimes compilers might do strange things with optimization, leading to such effects in debug. Since you are able to stop at the specific point, please [edit] your question to add the surrounding machine code, in assembly. You can also try to generate a listing file during compilation, which is preferred because of the additional information.

Comment: Thank you for the listings! You are working on your program between edit 2 and edit 3, and that rearranged the layout of the variables. Most probably all is well with the code in edit 3. The background is that the PIC cannot put local variables on the stack. Therefore, the compiler analyses the life time of each local variable and allocates different local variables _to the same memory_, if their life times do not overlap. What you see listed is the name of such an other local variable, which you want to check (you did not tell us about it). And it's clear that it is out of scope.

Comment: Anyway, the assembler statements show no error. The relevant operation is `MOVFF RCREG, v_aux2` (or `qtd_int_ext`, explained above). This reads the current value in the EUSART receiver FIFO and stores it in the variable. If you see 0x55 in `RCREG` before executing that operation, and 0x00 in `v_aux2` after executing that operation, I'm out of ideas. You might want to single step through this machine code to ensure that you see exactly that effect.

Comment: The next step I would do is to simplify the program as much as possible. Delete any other stuff, especially interrupts, buffers, any other task until only the reception is left, as simple as possible. You can do this incrementally to make sure that the issue is still present. If you are down to the bare minimum and still see the problem, add the complete program and the commands to compile and link  (that's the definition of [mre]) to your question, please. If the problem disappears during the course, you have a hint where the error is.

Comment: While debugging the code in the simulator, something have to do with the `RCSTAbits.ADDEN` bit. Maybe the simulation just thinks that, there is no address match, then it doesn't make sense to keep receiving the data, although you put it manually to the `RCREG` register. According to the datasheet you should clear the `ADDEN` bit to allow the received data into the receive buffer.

Comment: So considering that informartion; I think you meant `ADDEN = 0;` but mistakenly write `ADEN = 0;` just after checking the `0x55`.